# Is this a correct way of making modules in Lua?

Tags: module, lua

On the official lua wiki it states that this is how you make a module

```
local mymodule = {}

function mymodule.foo()
    print("Hello World!")
end

return mymodule
```

But couldn't you just do

```
return { foo=function() print("Hello World!") end }
```

I am familiar with Lua but not an expert. So is there anything wrong with what I've written?

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your variant.  But there are two inconvenient moments here.  1) One-liner is hard-to-read.  2) Inside your functions you're unable to access another functions of this module.  If you have two functions `foo` and `bar` then they couldn't invoke each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is perfectly fine.

The example in the wiki is better suited for larger modules, with several functions and possibly private data.